# Get XY coordinates of TextPointer within WPF Richtextbox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, coordinates

I would like to know if is possible to get XY coordinates of TextPointer within WPF Richtextbox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Mouse.GetPosition(MyRichTextBox)` which will return you the X,Y coordinates of the Mouse within the RichTextBox

Here's a simple example that I used to verify this was correct:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="Test" Height="100" Width="100" MouseMove="Test_MouseMove"  />
    <Label x:Name="Test2" Content="{Binding }" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Test_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Test2.DataContext = Mouse.GetPosition(this.Test);
}
```

**EDIT**

Didn't realize you wanted to get caret position instead of mouse position. Use `myRichTextBox.CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward)` to get the X,Y coordinates of the caret

Comment: Unfortunately I need to get coordinates of TextPointer, not mouse

Comment: @lale - Does it have to be a RichTextBox? TextBox has a GetRectFromCharacterIndex which can be used for that.... `textbox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textbox.CaretIndex)`

Answer (score 4):

```
Rect Example = myRichTextBox.CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward)
```

This will give the X,Y coordinates of the carete position